# Test a post method in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing

I wanted to write a test in angular for a post method. I'm very very new to testing in angular.

I have this service with has a post method:

```
export class ResourceService implements ErrorHandler {
    static readonly messageUrl: string = '/messages/data';

    postData(pairs: Request): Observable<number> {
    const url = `${this.makeUrl(ResourceService.messageUrl)}`;
    return this.httpClient.post<number>(url, pairs).pipe(
      first(),
      retry(1),
      catchError(error => {
        return this.handleError(error);
      })
    );
  }
}

export interface Request {
  pId?: number;
  sId?: number;
  filter: Filter
}
```

I just wanted to test if a post request will be triggered.

Here is the test which I wrote:

```
describe('ResourceService', () => {
       fit('should test if the request is triggered', async(async () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [
            DataModule,
            HttpClientTestingModule
          ],
        });

        let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
        const service: ResourceService = TestBed.get(ResourceService);

        const mockData: Request = {
          sId: 242,
          pId: 1020,
          filter: new Filter()
        };

        service.postData(mockData).subscribe(data =>
        expect(data).toBe(1)
        );

        const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(service.makeUrl(`/messages/data`));
        expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
        req.flush(mockData);
        httpTestingController.verify();
      }));

});
```

Unfortunately i get an error: 
Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: http://localhost:8088/messages/data", found none.

Then I tried to check if a post will be called without the mock data, and I got the same error. 
What would be the simplest way just at least to check this method? 
E.g. check if this method is a post, return true if it is a post or something similar.

If there is something unclear I'am available for clarifications.

Comment: no need to use the operator first, HttpClient emit a single event

Comment: @Chris which operator do you mean?

Comment: first() operator